# How do I fix 'Unprocessed view path found' error with ExceptionNotifier plugin in rails 2.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, plugins

After upgrading a rails 1.2 website to 2.1, the [ExceptionNotifier plugin](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/exception_notifier) no longer works, complaining about this error:

> ActionView::TemplateFinder::InvalidViewPath:  Unprocessed view path
>   found:
>   "/path/to/appname/vendor/plugins/exception_notification/lib/../views".
>   Set your view paths with #append_view_path, #prepend_view_path, or #view_paths=.

What causes it and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ought to upgrade to the newest Exception Notification plugin which is in [its new home at GitHub](http://github.com/rails/exception_notification/tree/master).

Answer (score 9):

This was caused by a change in rails 2.1 which prevents rails from loading views from any arbitrary path for security reasons.

There is now an updated version of the plugin on github, so the solution is to use that.

---

The old solution here for posterity

To work around it, edit `init.rb` under your `vendor/plugins/exception_notification` directory, and add the following code to the end

```
ActionController::Base.class_eval do
  append_view_path File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/lib/../views'
end
```

This adds the ExceptionNotifier plugins' views folder to the list, so it is allowed to load them.

Comment: thanks, i have to keep old plugin so the old solution si pretty handy for me